# Can a Table iterator "leak" into a Module?

Tags: programming, evaluation

I want to repeatedly call a module by using a Table statement.  When I use an `i` iterator in the Table command calling the module, I receive the error message "Table::itraw: Raw object 1 cannot be used as an iterator. >>"  The module also contains a separate Table statement with the `i` iterator.

I noticed that when I change the iterator in the Table statement calling the module to something else, say `v` I no longer get the error message above.  This makes me think the `i` iterator is leaking into the module, so ....

*Question 1*: Am I correct that the value of the `i` iterator from the Table statement calling the Module is leaking into the module?

*Question 2*: Is this expected behavior?

*Question 3*: Why does this happen?

*Question 4*: Is there another way to solve this problem, other than to avoid the use of `i` as an iterator in both the Table calling the module and the module itself?

Thank you for any advice!
Todd

---

Here is a snippet of the offending code:

```
errorcorrection[signaltype_,chipid_,probesetpostocheck_]:=Module[{clusters,positions,loopindex,groupminuscurrent,similarprobesets},

loopindex=1; (* initialize while loop index to 1; this loop continues for the length of the number of probesets that need checked for unusual signal - which is the length of the probesetpostocheck *)

While[loopindex<=2(*Length[probesetpostocheck[chipid]]*),

clusters=Flatten[Drop[Sort[FindClusters[signaltype[chipid][[probesetpostocheck[chipid][[loopindex]]]],3,DistanceFunction->EuclideanDistance,Method->"Agglomerate"]],-1]]; (* locate probe signals within the current probeset being evaluated that are unreliable and need replaced *)

Print[clusters];

With[{i=i},positions=Flatten[Table[Position[signaltype[chipid][[probesetpostocheck[chipid][[loopindex]]]],clusters[[i]]],{i,1,Length[clusters]}]]]

Print[positions];

If[MemberQ[controlchips,chipid],

(groupminuscurrent=DeleteCases[controlchips,x_/;x==chipid];
similarprobesets=Table[signaltype[groupminuscurrent[[i]]][[probesetpostocheck[chipid][[loopindex]]]],{i,1,Length[groupminuscurrent]}]),

(groupminuscurrent=DeleteCases[experimentchips,x_/;x==chipid];
similarprobesets=Table[signaltype[groupminuscurrent[[i]]][[probesetpostocheck[chipid][[loopindex]]]],{i,1,Length[groupminuscurrent]}])]

Print[similarprobesets];

loopindex++]]
```

---

```
run2 = Table[
  errorcorrection[pmsignal, experimentchips[[i]], pmpostocheck], {i, 
   1, 1}]


{11719.,1567.,2149.,2001.,1781.,1693.}

Table::itraw: Raw object 1 cannot be used as an iterator. >>

Table[Position[pmsignal[GSM356796][[pmpostocheck[GSM356796][[loopindex$112290]]]],clusters$112290[[1]]],{1,1,Length[clusters$112290]}]
```

---

```
run3 = Table[
  errorcorrection[pmsignal, experimentchips[[v]], pmpostocheck], {v, 
   1, 1}]

{11719.,1567.,2149.,2001.,1781.,1693.}

{7,6,8,9,17,20}
```

---

After considering everyone's responses below, I have been able to get my code to work better by replacing the `With[{i=i},positions=Flatten ....`  statement inside the errorcorrection module with `Module[{i=i},positions=Flatten ....`   As noted `Block` also works fine.

I am still puzzled, however, why `i` takes on a value of 1 inside the `errorcorrection` module, when the module is called by this statement:

```
run2 = Table[errorcorrection[pmsignal, experimentchips[[i]], pmpostocheck], {i, 1, 1}]
```

An example of output showing the iterator `i` is here:

```
run2 = Table[errorcorrection14[pmsignal, experimentchips[[i]], pmpostocheck], {i, 1, 1}]


{11719.,1567.,2149.,2001.,1781.,1693.}
```

`i` equals 1

```
{7,6,8,9,17,20}
```

*Question 5*: (continuing from numbering above): Doesn't the `Table` command in `run2=Table[errorcorrection14[pmsignal, experimentchips[[i]], pmpostocheck], {i, 1, 1}]`   localize the iterator?

*Question 6*: If so, why does that value show up in the `errorcorrection` module?

*Question 7*: If `i` did NOT take on the value of 1 (or any value) in the `errorcorrection` module, would my original `With[{i=i},positions=Flatten` statement have worked ok?

It seems to me (in my naivety) that the problem with using With in this case, is that `i` is taking on a value in the module from the `Table` statement calling the module .... but I thought Table should localize `i` and prevent its value from going into the module??

Thank you again, as I struggle to understand at a "deeper" level.

Comment: Not relevant for the *question*, but I think it's worth mentioning that `Table` is a function, not a statement.  A *statement* is a "phrase" that tells the computer to do something.  A function is something that returns a value.

Comment: @Todd I've expanded my answer to address your additional questions. Let me know if you suits your needs.

Comment: @rcollyer  Thank you for your time and excellent commentary.  Over the past few days I have been pouring over the documentation, and I was beginning to think along the lines that you communicated in your answer.  I appreciate your time investment!  I owe you a beer.  This goes to show that a biologist can learn a little Mathematica.

Comment: As a "newish" user, have you seen that we have a [syntax highlighter script](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118/52) available? It makes it a lot easier to read. Also, if your in the Northeastern US, I may actually be able to take you up on that offer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know the reason for the second giving you the error: `i` has been set to `1`. Under normal operations, this will not happen as `Table` has the `Attribute` [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAll.html), so even if `i` has a value, `Table` should be shielded from it. For example,

```
i = 5
Table[ i, {i , 3}]
(* Out[1] = 5 
   Out[2] = {1, 2, 3}
*)
```

However, in the large block of code, you use this construct:

```
With[{i = i}, Table[ ..., {i, ...} ]
```

So, it is likely that the second `Table` is executed in a similar manner, and that is where the problem lies. For instance,

```
With[{i = 1}, Table[i, {i, 5}]]
(* Table::itraw: Raw object 1 cannot be used as an iterator. >>
   Out[3] = Table[1, {1, 5}]
*)
```

[`With`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/52) operates by replacing `i` in `Table` with its value prior to `Table` doing anything which circumvents the `HoldAll`.  Neither, `Block` nor `Module` have the same effect, so I would advise using them, instead, for this type of thing.

---

In your code for `run2`, you effectively have this code

```
Table[ With[{i2 = i1}, Table[ ..., {i2, ...}]], {i1, ...}]
(* I have renamed the variables for clarity, but the results are the
   same with them all set to i*)
```

Here, `i1` is localized to the outer `Table` and the `With` sets `i2` to the value of `i1` which causes the error you're seeing.  The reason this shows up inside `errorcorrection` is that `i1` is not localized to `errorcorrection`, but takes on the global (to it) value.

Incidentally, this reveals that `Table` is using `Block` or `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` to perform its scoping. Consider,

```
f[x_] := {x, i}
Block[{i = 3}, f[q]]
Internal`InheritedBlock[{i = 3}, f[q]]
Module[{i = 3}, f[q]]
With[{i = 3}, f[q]]
(*
Out[131]= {q, 3}
Out[132]= {q, 3}
Out[133]= {q, i}
Out[134]= {q, i}
*)
```

which reveals one of the key differences between the [different scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/52). Here `i` in `f` is interpreted as `` Global`i ``, but `Module` and `With` effectively use [`Unique[i]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unique.html), instead. So, they return `` Global`i `` unevaluated.  (`With` actually performs a rewriting operation, but the effect is the same.) `Block` and `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` effectively define `` Unique[]`i `` and without any context qualifier on `i` in `f`, it is subsumed into the new context. The difference between them is that `Block` assumes that no definitions of `i` exists. But, `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` pulls in the global definitions into `` Unique[]` `` allowing for small changes to be made easily.

In the code, if `i` was not specified in the outer `Table` (as in the code for `run3`), then yes `With` would work as expected. But, the moral of the story is that `Table` need not be wrapped in any of scoping constructs as it does the scoping itself.

Comment: Yes, I was just about to type exactly that.  The purpose of `With` is to define local *constants*, which is exactly not what is wanted here.

Comment: I tend to use `With` to define local variables, is that bad practice? If so what are the consequences?

Comment: @image_doctor In the case of `Table` and other functions that take a `Symbol`, they're usually already localized via `HoldAll`. But, as a general method, I like to use `With` to define local variables, too. You just have to watch out how the variables will be used, like in the case of `Table`, above.

Comment: @image_doctor I think an important point is that `With` does not define local variables. Try `With[{i = 3}, i = 5]` to see what I mean (and compare to the same thing with `Block` or `Module`). It defines local constants; see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/561/16

Comment: @acl Yes I see your point :) I tend to use `With` blocks to compute once those things which I might need multiple times in a local context, often in conjunction with `Map` or something similar. So conceptually thought of them as variables, though in practice they aren't assigned to outside of the construction `{}`. Hence I didn't trip over their immutability.

Comment: Thank you to all for your assistance - especially rcollyer.  I have added to my initial question above because of some finer points that are still confusing to me.